# Issue with random sampling

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pick a random element from an array without picking the same element twice.

After a few iterations it is undefined.

It works with `return(pick_random_letter())`. But WHY?

Why does `pick_random_letter()` not go back and return later?

```js
let letters = [
{ name: 'A' },
{ name: 'B' },
{ name: 'C' },
{ name: 'D' },
]

let used_letters = [];

function pick_random_letter(){
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
  let next_letter = letters[random].name;
  if (used_letters.includes(next_letter)){
    if (used_letters.length == letters.length) used_letters = [];
    pick_random_letter(); // return(pick_random_letter()) works
  }else{
    used_letters.push(next_letter);
    return next_letter;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    let random_letter = pick_random_letter();
    console.log(random_letter);
    console.log(used_letters);
}
```

Working example:

```js
let letters = [
{ name: 'A' },
{ name: 'B' },
{ name: 'C' },
{ name: 'D' },
]

let used_letters = [];

function pick_random_letter(){
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
  let next_letter = letters[random].name;
  if (used_letters.includes(next_letter)){
    if (used_letters.length == letters.length) used_letters = [];
    return(pick_random_letter());
  }else{
    used_letters.push(next_letter);
    return next_letter;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    let random_letter = pick_random_letter();
    console.log(random_letter);
    console.log(used_letters);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: In the if condition, you basically call the function again, but do not return it, Hence, you get `undefined`. You need to return the value returned by the function (which you are doing in working example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off using a shuffling approach. Create a shuffled list of your letters and pick from these. This avoids any need to check if we've returned a letter previously.

We'd start by creating a shuffledLetters array, then each time we call pick_random_letter() we return the next value.

The `shuffle()` function here is a basic [Fisher–Yates / Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}

let letters = [
  { name: 'A' },
  { name: 'B' },
  { name: 'C' },
  { name: 'D' },
]

// Create a shuffled copy of the letters array
let shuffledLetters = shuffle([...letters]);

function pick_random_letter() {
  return shuffledLetters.pop();
}

for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  let random_letter = pick_random_letter();
  console.log(random_letter);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```